# What is the settings to run cypress test in Bamboo Continuous Integration

Tags: cypress, bamboo

My cypress test cases are available at bitbucket repo. I want to run these tests in Bamboo CI
After selecting task type - I cant understand what should I use here.

[image]

Also, Where I need to put the command to run the cypress testcases in Bamboo (Command for headless, I use : npx cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/filename.spec.js")

Any clear guideline to make the job done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9355411/bkucera Any idea How it should be done?

Answer (score 1):

You should run your Cypress tests using Docker. There is a dedicated docker image, maintained by Cypress for this task.
See: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/05/02/run-cypress-with-a-single-docker-command/
The "included"-Images contain a specific browser/Cypress version.
It is easier to ensure, your tests are running against the same setup they were written against.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward response to your question would be to run a "Script" task. make sure you set the right "Working subdirectory" for it.

Assuming you are using maven for building, you can add a mvn goal that will execute the tests and then trigger it using the "Maven" task. The benefit of "Maven" task is that it also allows you to easily set test results to be

you can also run a "Script" task